# How do I rip out the apple's m4v subtitle?

Tags: itunes, video, subtitle, itunes-u

How do I rip out the apple's m4v video format's subtitle for reading? Personally sometimes I just want to read through what the video said rather than having to go through the video. Does any one knows how to do this?